# Anchor not triggered

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

I have a code to export json data to Excel via javascript, it works fine in Chrome. However the same code doesn't work in IE where a click event is fired via code:

```
download = function (content, filename, contentType) {
    if (!contentType) contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
    var a = document.getElementById('idA');
    var blob = new Blob([content], {
        'type': contentType
    });
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = filename;
    var eid = '#' + id;
    //$(eid)[0].click();
    var l = document.getElementById('idL');
    alert('1'); //this one works
    l.click();  
    alert('2'); //this doesn't  
};
```

download function is fired by clicking a button and clicking anchor href causes blob downloading in Excel. I need to make this work in IE.

Comment: Where is `id` coming from in `var a = document.getElementById(id);`?

Comment: @Tobias Kun it's an argument of outer function

Comment: Download attribute is not support in IE at all http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: `.click` function is supported in every browser , though it might give some issues in Safari

Comment: you can also try using `Jquery click` function. jQuery('#id')[0].click();

Comment: @SoorajChandran pls see the code above, I've tried

Comment: Have you included JQuery file that is supported by your IE version ? just asking since this is a common thing to forget.

Comment: @SoorajChandran yeah, all other features work